# Selectively zip files up to 50M

Tags: bash, shell

I want to select all the files in a folder that starts with "data*" and choose the latest files by date such that the compressed zip file of the selected files should not exceed 50MB. How can I do that in a bash script?

I am fine with iteratively adding files to the zip folder and checking the size, but I have to make sure that the most recent files are added first.

Answer (score 1):

Selecting the most recent data file is simple using `ls -t`.  This returns a list of files ordered by what was modified most recently, and that matches your string.  I would put this list in a .txt file somewhere

```
ls -t data* > lsResults.txt
```

As for the zipping, that is trial and error.  I cant tell you how a big a file will be until its compressed.  I can give you a guess, but without knowing what data is in your file, there is no way I can answer.

However, my recommendation would be to use what ever command line archiver (like 7-zip) you have to add your data files one by one until you get close to 50MB. Once you go over 50MB, just remove the last file added and stop the loop.

Here is my example script. You will probably have to tweak it to suit your needs.

```
#!/bin/sh

ls -t data* > lsResults.txt
actualSize=0
maximumSize=50000000
archive=/my/data/archive.zip

for $filename in lsResults.txt; do
    #I will pretend you are using 7zip
    #You will have to change this to use what ever archiver you are have
    7za add -zip $archive $filename

    #get the size of the archive
    actualSize=$(wc -c < $archive)

    #check the size of the archive
    if [ $actualSize -gt $maximumSize ]; then
        #File size is over 50MB
        #Delete the last file added to the archive
        7z d $archive $filename
        #stop the loop so we dont keep adding files
        break;
    else
        #file is under 50MB, keep adding data
        #do nothing here
    fi
done
```